# Finding the upper and lower Riemann-sums of trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

I am asked to find Riemann-sums for the function $f(x) = \cos x, x \in [0, 2\pi], n = 4 \rightarrow \Delta x = \frac{\pi}{2}$

I was able to get the correct answers by intuition, but I have some trouble understanding how the process works. For the lower riemann sum, we have that

$$L_{f, P_4} = \frac{\pi}{2}(f(\pi/2) + f(\pi) + f(\pi) + f(\frac{3\pi}{2}) = -\pi$$

I have not worked with curves that changes from positive to negative like these together with Riemann-sums before, but I was able to get the correct answers by intuitevely thinking that is needs to have four factors, and only the lower ones are to be counted. However, I am very insecure about my hypothese where I decided to add $f(\pi)$ twice. What's the logic here?

Comment: You always choose the minimum value on the sub-interval to find the lower sum. So the first term should be $f(\pi/2) = 0$ not $f(0) = 1$. The other terms are correct though.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: I think that it was just a typo as his computation would be incorrect otherwise. Still good to point out, but I don't want to diminish his own effort :)

Comment: @Clayton : Good point - I didn't even check to see if the RHS was correct or not :)

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, as Clayton pointed out. In other words, for every interval, I choose the minimum value, and given that $\pi$ is the minimun value on both $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]$ and ${[\pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}}]$, it is to be chosen for both?